# How do I increase the amount of stone that spawns vertically in a Minecraft world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I'm starting an SMP where everyone works mainly underground, so we need a lot more underground to work with vertically speaking. Is there a way to basically generate the world a lot higher on the Y axis, so there's a lot more stone and stuff underneath? I looked through the customization settings in 1.12.2 but I'm not sure what exactly the stuff on the last two pages do. I kind of want to world to look something like this: https://ibb.co/n8VXssK

Comment: You probably need a mod.

Answer (score -1):

I think I may have found a solution for what you are asking. I went into the world creation menu and changed the World Type to Superflat. From there, click Customize below it and then click the Presets button and select Tunnelers dream. This gives one layer of grass blocks, followed by 5 layers of dirt, then 230 layers of stone, and finally one layer of bedrock. Since this is superflat it would generate a completely flat top but it does give you a looooot more under ground to work with. Heres a screenshot of the layer settings I mentioned to give visual aid.

[image: layers]

Comment: I'm not sure superflat will do. We still want biomes and oceans and stuff, but I'll experiment around with it.